# Python pyautogui Windows 11 control shift leftarrowkey combo fails

Tags: python, pyautogui

I want to execute this key combo so the current window switches to a second monitor.
It just doesn´t work and I dont know why.

I tried following:

```
pyautogui.keyDown("win")
pyautogui.keyDown("shift")
pyautogui.press('left')
pyautogui.keyUp("shift")
pyautogui.keyUp("win")
```

Also tried:

`pyautogui.hotkey('win', 'shift', 'left')`

Need help

Answer (score 0):

```
pyautogui.hotkey('win', 'ctrl', 'left')
```

There is nothing wrong with the code you have provided. The problem is the shortcut is Windows+Ctrl+Left, not Windows+Shift+Left.

Comment: weird, I use an german keyboard layout and for me and every other german layout user its Windows+Shift+Left. Actually there happens nothing when I do Windows+Ctrl+Left

Comment: what is the combination for your keyboard?

Comment: Its win+shift+left

Comment: Does the Win+Ctrl+Left code work on your computer anyway?